# How to group the results by country in SQL or Report builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssms, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have a question: I am using report builder to build some reports. And I got stuck in this place where I want to sum all the results of one month to be in one cell.

[image]

For example, in this picture you see that under the country1 I have 2 "1" I want them to be in one line and the sum/total will be 2

I tried to group by country... but it didn't make any difference in the view.

How can I do that?

Is there a way to do it via the report builder or through my SQL query?

Thank you

NOTE: I used this code to get the days field in the report builder

```
=iif(Fields!Date_WEEKDAY__NUMBER_.Value=1,"Sunday",
iif(Fields!Date_WEEKDAY__NUMBER_.Value=2,"Monday",
iif(Fields!Date_WEEKDAY__NUMBER_.Value=3,"Tuesday",
iif(Fields!Date_WEEKDAY__NUMBER_.Value=4,"Wednesday",
iif(Fields!Date_WEEKDAY__NUMBER_.Value=5,"Thrusday",
iif(Fields!Date_WEEKDAY__NUMBER_.Value=6,"Friday",
iif(Fields!Date_WEEKDAY__NUMBER_.Value=7,"Saturday","Null")))))))
```

[image: 1]

[image]

[image]

And this is my main query in SQL:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT([Patient ID]) AS ID, 
    Activity,Date, [Interaction Type], [Adverse Event Occurred], 
    [Product Complaint Occurred], [Cancellation Reason], Created, 
    Status, [Interaction Reason], Country, Drug, 
    [Registered Nurse], [Created by], 
    YEAR(Date) AS [Date Year], 
    DATENAME(MONTH, Date) AS [Date Month], 
    DATENAME(WEEK, Date) AS [Date WEEK], 
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date) AS [Date WEEKDAY],
    DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date) AS [Date WEEKDAY (NUMBER)]
FROM
    MNZL_Patient_Activities
GROUP BY 
    ID, Activity, Date, [Interaction Type], [Adverse Event Occurred], 
    [Product Complaint Occurred], [Cancellation Reason], 
    Created, Status, [Interaction Reason], Country, Drug, 
    [Registered Nurse], [Created by], YEAR(Date), 
    DATENAME(MONTH, Date), DATENAME(WEEK, Date), 
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date)
HAVING 
    ([Interaction Reason] = N'Medication Administration')
ORDER BY
    DATENAME(WEEK, Date)
```

Comment: It looks like you already have a rowgroup that groups by Year/Month/Day, so you can just edit the rowgroup properties and include Country in the Group By colums.

Comment: Are you using Column Grouping for your Days? You'll need to SUM the values.

Comment: Hello,

I already have it grouped by all. YEAR/MONTH/WEEK/COUNTRY. and i have a column group of the days

Answer (score 1):

This Query gonna sums all the ones in a "country line" and gives you back the total under a column named total
The "ISNULL" command is to avoid some trubles due to the sum between 1+"NULL"
It substitutes the values null if it's present with zero

```
SELECT  MT.[YEAR],
        MT.[ENROLMENT DATE],
        MT.[ENROLMENT DATE WEEK],
        MT.[COUNTRY],
        ISNULL(MT.SUNDAY,0)+
        ISNULL(MT.MONDAY,0)+
        ISNULL(MT.TUESDAY,0)+
        ISNULL(MT.WEDNESDAY,0)+
        ISNULL(MT.THRUSDAY,0)+
        ISNULL(MT.FRIDAY,0)+
        ISNULL(MT.SATURDAY,0)   AS TOTAL
FROM    MyTable MT
```

Comment: One thing i forgot to mention is that i set up the days code in the report builder, not in my original query.

using this code:

` =iif(Fields!Date_WEEKDAY__NUMBER_.Value=1,"Sunday",
iif(Fields!Date_WEEKDAY__NUMBER_.Value=2,"Monday",
iif(Fields!Date_WEEKDAY__NUMBER_.Value=3,"Tuesday",
iif(Fields!Date_WEEKDAY__NUMBER_.Value=4,"Wednesday",
iif(Fields!Date_WEEKDAY__NUMBER_.Value=5,"Thrusday",
iif(Fields!Date_WEEKDAY__NUMBER_.Value=6,"Friday",
iif(Fields!Date_WEEKDAY__NUMBER_.Value=7,"Saturday","Null"))))))) `

Answer (score 0):

I got it.. it was a silly mistake missed by me..
i didnt delete the "Details" grouping.. and it was grouping IDs
Causing each ID to go in separate row... Once i removed it it grouped IDs based on the month (The desired result)

Feeling extra stupid right now :)

Anyways, thank you very much everyone <3

[image]